# Corona SDK Build setting default orientation depending on device

Tags: iphone, plist, coronasdk

I am working on a Corona sdk project.
I have been looking all over for a solution to my issue and can't find anything.

What I would like to do is set the build setting so that if the app is on an iPhone, only portrait orientation is supported.  If the app is on iPad, I would like to have only landscape supported.

Would it be possible to do something like setting the orientation array inside the iPhone plist?

```
settings = {
 iphone ={
  plist={
   orientation= {
    default = "portrait",  
    content = "portrait",
    supported = {"portrait" }
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

or just change the values contained inside the table from the plist?

```
settings = {
  orientation= {      
    supported = {"landscapeRight", "landscapeLeft","portrait", "portraitUpsideDown"}
  }
 iphone ={
  plist={
   orientation.default="portrait"

  }
 }
}
```

Maybe i am just looking at the issue the wrong way but at this point I cant seem to find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use build.settings like that.  It's not supported.  You're best bet is to determine if you are an iPad or iPhone in your code and position your elements accordingly or produce separate versions of your app, an iPad only and an iPhone only.